# Bash syntax error when commented out if block content: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'

Tags: bash

Why does this simple if statement result in a syntax error?

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ 1 == 1 ]] ; then
#    echo "hello"
fi
```

The error is

> line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'

It works as expected if the echo is uncommented.

#### Edit

Thanks, fixed the error using `:`.   Silly bash.  =P

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ 1 == 1 ]] ; then
:#    echo "hello"
fi
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because, as you can see in [man bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), the correct syntax for `if` is

```
if list; then list; [ elif list; then list; ] ... [ else list; ] fi
```

And if you look up the definition of `list`, it says

> A list is a sequence of one or more pipelines separated by one of the
>   operators ;, &, &&, or ││, and optionally terminated by one of ;, &,
>   or .

This "one or more" is the reason why your example is not a valid syntax.